# Columns get cut off on pdfmake

Tags: angular, pdfmake

I am using pdfmake for generating a report as a table format. The table column has more than 10 columns so only 5 columns are displayed I want to cut off the remaining column and display next page on reaming columns. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: ok and where is your code?

Comment: @just code, i can't share my code. Please can you give some idea, how to display cut off columns in next page.

Comment: @R.ArunKumar it seems really difficult to know what you've already attempted or not without any code. Is there really no way for you to share your code through a platform like https://codesandbox.io or anything else that can help us ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cutting off the remaining column and displaying them on next page, change the pageOrientation to landscape. You can do it as follow:

```
pageSize: 'A4',
pageOrientation: 'landscape',
```

Even If this does not solve your issue then also adjust fontsize of your columns.